# Application Permissions for Calendars.ReadWrite

Tags: php, office365, outlook-restapi

[Application Permissions for Calendars.ReadWrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Se1.jpg)

I am using this https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
here I need to want Calendars.ReadWrite for User Can Consent.
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, users cannot consent to these. Only IT admin can give the consent on behalf of the users of the organization. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications), 'example of consent experience' section.